# stack overflow in swing at processKeyEvent

Tags: java, user-interface, stack

I'm battling an error I don't quite understand.
I have a class in Java, let's call it `DownloadTable` derived from a `JDTable`.
Each of these classes implement `KeyListener`.

I'd like the base class `JDTable` to handle some keystrokes, so I put `this.AddListener(this)` in its constructor and create a key handler

> public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {...}

then I'd like the derived class `DownloadTable` to do some special keyboard processing of its own, so I repeat the process and add keyboard handler there too.
I also added a call to `super.processKeyEvent()` from the derived class' key handler to wire together the derived handler and the base handler.

The problem is that it doesn't work as expected and I'm getting a stack overflow exception whenever `super.ProcessKeyEvent` is called. When run in debugger, the parent's event handler isn't even called. Am I missing something obvious? Isn't `super.processKeyEvent()` going to somehow invoke superclass' `keyPressed()` handler? Thanks.

attached stack:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at jd.gui.swing.jdgui.views.downloadview.DownloadTable.keyPressed(DownloadTable.java:253)
>       at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at jd.gui.swing.jdgui.views.downloadview.DownloadTable.keyPressed(DownloadTable.java:253)
>       at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at jd.gui.swing.jdgui.views.downloadview.DownloadTable.keyPressed(DownloadTable.java:253)
>       at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)

Comment: Post the content of the DownloadTable.keyPressed method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, all of them are correct.

Apparently I've figured out the problem. I've mixed up awt's `processKeyEvent()` and `KeyListener`.

The proper solution to this was to add

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { ...
```

to the base method. Now events in both base and derived methods are being handled.

Still, the weird thing is that `KeyAdapter` works for me and `KeyListener` does not. What's not working is when I make the base class implement `KeyListener` and add method `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { ... }` - it never gets called. As I said above, when I use `KeyAdapter` inline, it gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

When `processKeyEvent()` calls the registered listeners to propagate key events, a listener should not call back to `processKeyEvent()` or the result is an infinite recursion as you have seen.

What is the reason you added the call? Is something ot working when you remove it?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like the base class JDTable to
>   handle some keystrokes

You should NOT be overriding the processKeyEvent(). You should be using [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). The provided link shows you the existing binds for each Swing component and provides a link to the Swing tutorial on "Using Key Bindings".